# Migrated My Profile link still pointing to the old MOSS server

Tags: my-site, administration, migration

Migrated a MOSS content DB to a brand new farm. The My Sites also were on the same content DB. Then the SSP also was migrated over. However, the My Profile link is not binding to the restored My Sites but rather to the old MOSS server. Anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, It was a mistake by our client. They had modified the MySite's default.aspx to redirect to the old server on page load. *Sigh

Appreciate all the help :-)!

Answer (score 0):

I think that Gary Lapointe has some STSADM extensions defined to help out here.  Here is a blog entry on his blog that you can possibly use.

http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/my-site-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

If only the links to the users's MySites are wrong but the rest of the migration works, you could iterate over the existing user profiles to set the PersonalUrl property to the new location.

Comment: I agree.  We have to do this when someone changes their alias (i.e. marrage, divorce, or anything requiring a name change).